# How to find a wordpress filter plugin for the header?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the homepage of my wordpress site, I want to put a filter under the menu bar (most popular post, highest rating, oldest post, recommend post, etc.).

I found several filter plugins, and most of them are located in the sidebar. So is there any horizontal filter plugin?

I am expecting the filter to look like the sample picture below [3-4 button][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following filter plugin : [Beautiful taxonomy filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/beautiful-taxonomy-filters/)

It provides filtering by posttype,taxonomy,terms and you need to make custom popular,featured and recommanded categories to filter them as taxonomy and terms. You also can use plugin API filters to customize the display. You can find the API section in the plugin documentation in the same link.

Answer (score 0):

What I see in your screenshot looks more like Tabs. You could use [Tabby Responsive Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabby-responsive-tabs/) and add your content under each tab.